# Rest assured - Response body displays null value for Success

Tags: arrays, rest-assured

Response body displays null value for Success

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w55rf.png]

**POJO :**

```
public class Employee {

public String name;
public int salary;
public int age;

public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee[name=" + name + ",salary=" + salary + ",age=" + age + "]";
}
```

**JSON Reader Class :**

```
public class ReadJsonFile < T > {


         public < T > List < T > getjsondata(String filepath, Class < T > typeofT) {

             //filepath= "src/test/resource/testdataresource/addplacerequest.json";
             Gson gson = new Gson();;
             BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
             try {

                 bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));


                 //Type ListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Addbook>>(){}.getType();
                 Type ListType = TypeToken.getParameterized(ArrayList.class, typeofT).getType(); //
                 //gson.toJson(ReadJsonFile,ListType);
                 //return new Gson().fromJson(bufferReader, ListType);

                 List < T > arraylist = gson.fromJson(bufferReader, ListType);

                 return (arraylist);

             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 throw new RuntimeException("Json file not found at path : " + filepath);
             } finally {
                 try {
                     if (bufferReader != null) bufferReader.close();
                 } catch (IOException ignore) {}
             }
         }
}
```

**Class to Read Pojo and Json Reader :**

```
public class TestDataBuild {


    public static List < Employee > employee() {
        ReadJsonFile < Employee > readJson = new ReadJsonFile < Addbook > ();

        List < Addbook > employee = readJson.getjsondata("src/test/resource/testDataResource/addplacerequest.json", Employee.class);


        //Retrieve data from JsonObject and create Employee bean

        for (int i = 0; i < employee.size(); i++) {
            //System.out.println(addbook.get(i).name);
            addbook.get(i).setName(employee.get(i).name);
            addbook.get(i).setAge(employee.get(i).age);
            addbook.get(i).setSalary(employee.get(i).salary);


        }

        return Employee;


    }


}
```

Comment: Is this resolved ?

Comment: No,If you got solution please share